# How spring internally creates object based on configurations

Tags: spring, namespaces, instantiation

Can some one shed some light on how spring creates objects for the configurations based on namespace. for eg.

```
  <jms:jca-listener-container resource-adapter="myResourceAdapter"
                        destination-resolver="myDestinationResolver"
                        transaction-manager="myTransactionManager"
                        concurrency="10">

<jms:listener destination="queue.orders" ref="myMessageListener"/>
```

I want to know what goes on internally, how spring instantiates the object. Pointer to the code in the framework which does this would be of great help

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the [brief explanation](http://blog.springsource.org/2006/08/28/creating-a-spring-20-namespace-use-springs-abstractbeandefintionparser-hierarchy/) of the internal workings. You can also look at [short tutorial](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1364131/Authoring-Custom-Namespaces-in-Spring-20) on TSS.